# Custom joomla Component to load data

Tags: php, joomla

I am new in joomla. I am working joomla component which was developed by other coder. I can edit page view, data etc which is displaying on page. But I am unable to find from where I can edit data which is coming from default. There is controller table in component, but if I remove controller folder still its loads.
In my one of view file I put this

```
print_r($this);
die("");
```

It prints all the data which is related to this component. I want to find code from where this data is coming so i can edit that data as per requirement. Its all only one view file, because controller folder in this component is removed.
This is somewhere in joomla main files.
Thanks

Comment: Did you checked in models folder? if not go into models folder and look for file with name having same name as view name.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit hard without seing any code, but assuming the original author followed joomla standards, the data comes from the model having the same name as the view.

e.g for `com_xyz/views/viewa/view.html.php`, the model would be `com_xyz/models/viewa.php`